# Components importing HeadlessUI throwing errors when built and then used in another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, module, headless-ui

I am currently developing a UI Library using **React, Tailwind, HeadlessUI and Storybook**.
Once I finished the components, and made sure that they worked in Storybook and on a react dev server, I built them and packaged them into a **private npm package**.

Most of them work fine when I **import them in a test project** using the created package, but some don't.
All of the not-working components share one thing in common: Importing something from `@headlessui/react`.
(The working components don't import anything from headlessui)

When I try using these components in my test project, they all throw the same error:
(Here I chose the component 'Select' as an example)

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'Select'.`

The error doesn't really make sense, because those components are exported from my library and imported into my test project **exactly the same** as the components that work. I even checked that by using a simple `console.log` on all components. It came out the same.
Here is how they are imported and exported:

```js
// imported into test project:
import { Select, Form, Dropdown, /* ... */ } from "@my-package";
```

```js
//exported from the library in index.js:
// ...
import Select from "./components/Select";
export { Select, /* ... */ };
```

Because I am sure that I imported them correctly into my test project, i am certain that it must have something to do with the build or HeadlessUI.

For building I am using **babel**.
Although babel **never threw errors while building**, I figured that I'd still post the confs here.
My build script: `"build": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=production babel src -d dist"`
My .babelrc:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "react-app",
      {
        "absoluteRuntime": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-react-css-modules"]
}
```

**Here is some of the non-built and built code from the component 'Select':**

```js
// Select.jsx
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Listbox, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, SelectorIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Select({
  //...
}) {
  const selects = options;
  let selectedOption;
  let i = 0;
  selects.map((select) => {
    if (select.default) {
      selectedOption = selects[i];
      return true;
    }
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(selectedOption);

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        {({ open }) => (
          <>
            <Listbox.Label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
              {title}
            </Listbox.Label>
            <div className="mt-1 relative">
              <Listbox.Button
                className={` bg-white relative border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-primary/60 focus:border-primary sm:text-sm ${
                  !length || length === "md"
                    ? "w-72"
                    : length === "fit"
                    ? "w-full"
                    : length === "lg"
                    ? "w-96"
                    : length === "sm" && "w-44"
                }`}
              >
              // ...
```

```js
// Select.js
"use strict";

var _interopRequireWildcard = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard").default;

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault").default;

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = Select;
exports.getSelected = getSelected;

var _slicedToArray2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/slicedToArray"));

var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(require("react"));

var _react2 = require("@headlessui/react");

var _solid = require("@heroicons/react/solid");

function Select(_ref) {
// ...
return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(_react.default.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(_react2.Listbox.Label, {
      className: "block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
    }, title), /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("div", {
      className: "mt-1 relative"
    }, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(_react2.Listbox.Button, {
      className: " bg-white relative border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-primary/60 focus:border-primary sm:text-sm ".concat(!length || length === "md" ? "w-72" : length === "fit" ? "w-full" : length === "lg" ? "w-96" : length === "sm" && "w-44")
    }, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("span", {
      className: "block truncate ".concat(placeholder && !selected ? "text-gray-400" : "text-gray-700")
    }, selected ? selected.text : placeholder), /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("span", {
      className: "absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none"
    }, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(_solid.SelectorIcon, {
      className: "h-5 w-5 text-gray-400",
      "aria-hidden": "true"
    }))), // ...
```

Quick Summary:

- Components that import headlessui don't render/work like intended.
- The fault is probably not the importing/exporting but rather the building or HeadlessUI.

I am not sure what to make of this.
**Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!**

Comment: Did you figure the issue ? I have the exact same problem, I create a component using headlessUI ComboBox component and get the same error as you

Comment: @SuperMarco No, I don't. And I really have no clue what the problem could be.

Comment: That's okay, I found a work around for it. I am using rollup, not webpack and found this addons https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve which can bundle node modules dependency with your code. 
I just used it and specified which package and it worked.

Maybe there is the same with webpack that will allow you to bundle HeadlessUI into your code. It's not ideal but it worked for me :)

Comment: @SuperMarco as I already mentioned in another comment on this question, I am no longer in need of an answer to this. 
I am going to leave this question opened, for other people.
But thank you so much for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way the headless-ui package.json is referencing the entry point. In the node_modules folder in your custom component after you've installed it you will see a reference to _react2 = require('@headlessui/react'). If you look at the value of that it is a string path to file that doesn't exist:

**'/static/media/index.bad31bab1c06d3ff486c.cjs'**

If you look at the package.json file for this library you will see it points to a cjs file when being required. Because most applications/components these days are built with webpack, babel, etc it will always use the require:

[image]

If you go into that built file in your component and force it to be a module by adding the line of code below so it picks up the .js file you will see it work. So **this is not an answer to the question** because this is something the library owners are going to have to fix, it is just the reason you are seeing the issue.

[image]

The issue is

Comment: What an absolute legend. 
As mentioned I don't have access to the source code anymore, but this answer seems very logical and like it should work. 
Thank you for solving this very specific problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you exported your components inside `index.js` is wrong. You should use the "barrel" way.

> A barrel is a way to rollup exports from several modules into a single
> convenient module. The barrel itself is a module file that re-exports
> selected exports of other modules.

```
export * as Select from "./components/Select";
```

Resource: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that doesn't help either.
Before creating this question I even tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @phil-not-funny can you maybe try to use "@babel/preset-react" as preset instead of react-app. You need to install this preset as part of your dev dependencies.

`{"presets": ["@babel/preset-react" ]}`

Comment: please know, that I appreciate your help, but I made this post back in summer when I had an internship at a company and I needed that part to work. Now, my internship is over and I lost my access to the code. If I could, I would try out your fix, but I unfortunately can't.
I will keep this Question opened for anyone, that has the same problem, but I am not in need for an answer anymore.
Thank you so much for trying to help me out with my (now not anymore) problem!